# How to import Processing libraries into Java application

Tags: java, processing

I am calling Processing functions from Java code.

This works fine for the standard Processing classes, but how to you import other Processing libraries; e.g. gicentre?

I've actually got it working by extracting the jar file from the processing library and then manually installing the artifact into the maven project.

Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: What are "standard Processing functions"?  Why do you capitalize "processing"?  The proper way would be to add all 3rd party JARs as dependencies in your Maven pom.xml.  I can't tell what you're doing from the question.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>  

add in  your Maven pom.xm

Comment: @SandipSolanki you should expand you comment as an answer. It's great!

Comment: @duffymo Capitalised because it is a name, of a programming language. The maven dependency search for the libraries does not return results, except for the core functions (core.jar).

Comment: @duffymo by "standard Processing functions" I mean those within core.jar.

Comment: Whose core.jar?   Where does that come from?

Comment: @duffymo Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is a language that can be used as a Java library. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: Didn't know @KevinWorkman, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `dependancy` in your maven `pom.xml` file.

```
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core --> 
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.processing</groupId> 
   <artifactId>core</artifactId> 
   <version>2.2.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: this only imports the core library and not external libraries, such as gicentre.  The maven dependency search for the external libraries does not return any results.

Comment: The latest version of Processing is 3.3.6. Version 2.2.1 should not be used anymore unless you have a specific reason to use an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Sandip's answer will work for the core Processing library (with the caveat that you should use the latest version, not version 2.2.1), but like you've discovered, gicentre doesn't have a maven repository.

You can download the various gicentre libraries from [this page](https://www.gicentre.net/software/). Each of those libraries comes as a `.zip` file that contains a `.jar` file.

Now that you have the `.jar` file, it's just a matter of adding that `.jar` to your classpath. How you do that depends on how you've set up your project. The simplest way to do it is to use the command line to compile your project, and then you'd use the `-cp` argument. You've said you're using Maven, so Googling "maven local jar" will lead to a ton of results, including this one: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)

But note that you don't have to use Maven. You could just set the classpath yourself, either via the command line or via your IDE settings. For simple projects, this can be a better option, especially if Maven is giving you trouble.

Comment: I would recommend using Maven.  The thing to do is to mvn install those JARs into your local .m2 repository.  The benefits of Maven should not be discarded lightly.

Comment: @duffymo Fair enough. But I would also say that the complexity of Maven should not be dismissed either. There are pros and cons that should be considered. Especially if OP is confused about how the classpath works in general, it could be a good idea to get some more practice under their belt before using Maven.

Comment: Fair enough.  Your profile says you lurk in the processing tag and work at Google.  This is a new library for me.  What's the story?  I've never heard of it until today.

Comment: @duffymo Haha, my day job and my lurking in the Processing tag aren't related. Processing is a language/library that makes it easy to create visual, interactive programs without a ton of boilerplate code. Check it out: https://processing.org/

Comment: As I said in my query I manually added the .jar extracted from the gicentre Processing library as a local jar using maven. Just thought there might be a more direct way of doing it.

Comment: @PerceptualRobotics The most direct way to do it is to set the classpath yourself. If you're using Maven, then there isn't a better way to do it.